# Combine, Sum, and Take Highest Value based on duplicates in more than one column

Tags: vba, sum, duplicates

I have a spreadsheet where I need to combine rows based on values in Column A and B. Column C needs to be summed, while column D only needs to pull the highest value. In the Example, I need the first three rows combined (Columns A and B match) where Column C is summed, and return Column D as 1300.7 since it is the highest value. Rows 5 and 6 need to remain untouched since the column A values are duplicates, but the column B values are unique.

```
KWSQ    FTHG    1300.7  1300.7  
KWSQ    FTHG    85  85  
KWSQ    FTHG    -85 -85  
SOBL    TFVL    150 150  
SOBL    QLLI    964.62  964.62
```

Desired Output

```
KWSQ    FTHG    1300.7  1300.7  
SOBL    TFVL    150     150  
SOBL    QLLI    964.62  964.62
```

I'm not going to lie, I've been too hung up on combining based on Column A and B, that I haven't tried anything. I cannot find a resource on this. Just pointing me in the right direction on how to reference both Columns A and B would be what I need most. I really appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Do you need to use vba?

Comment: You can achieve this using Excel Functions, no need for VBA. Copy Column A on in Column F & after selecting the Copied Data, remove duplicates from it. Then in Column I u can apply Formula like `SumIf` to get the sum of Values.

Comment: @AAA VBA is really the only programming I know, and I'm fairly novice at that.

Comment: @Mikku My only problem is this is just a sample. The actual date is 100k rows longish. I also need to make sure it only combines of both columns A and B are a duplicate. Will remove duplicates do that?

Comment: Ah, gotcha. How would I keep the rows lined up that way?

Comment: I also have this looped into another macro that's editing the data in other way (there are also 20 or so more columns), and I was trying to do a "click this button and all of this happens" scenario.

Comment: I have read through this a few times and maybe I am missing something but couldn't you just copy and paste columns A and B as values then remove the dupes using Excels remove duplicates function then use a `maxifs` formula?

Comment: @DanDonoghue, if you delete duplicates, how would you get the values of C and D?

Comment: @AAA into a separate area for output. Leave the base data and have a unique reporting section elsewhere (another sheet, or a different range on the same sheet).

Comment: @DanDonoghue, I get you now. Thank you. OP said they have over 100K rows 20 cols, so maybe they prefer to automate? Actually, if the data is sorted by A and B, then D descending, it becomes trivial. Still, that might be very slow (SumIfs over 100K rows of the original data, for each row of unique data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that will get you started. I did not test it. I commented the code, and put assumptions at the start. Important: input has to be sorted by the first two columns, and then by the last column in descending order so that the maximum value appears on the first row.

The code has to be placed in the code window of the sheet containing the data, for otherwise the `Cells()` function will not get the correct values.

```
Sub Combine()

    ' Assume data is in columns A through D.
    ' Assume that data ends when column A is empty.
    ' Assume that combined data is to be written to columns F through I.
    ' Assume input data is sorted by column A, then B, and then D in descending order.

    Dim outputRowIndex As Integer
    outputRowIndex = 1

    Dim inputRowIndex As Integer
    inputRowIndex = 1

    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(inputRowIndex, 1))

        If IsEmpty(Cells(outputRowIndex, 6)) Then

            ' Copy values in columns A to D to output columns F to I.
            Cells(outputRowIndex, 6).Value2 = Cells(inputRowIndex, 1).Value2
            Cells(outputRowIndex, 7).Value2 = Cells(inputRowIndex, 2).Value2
            Cells(outputRowIndex, 8).Value2 = Cells(inputRowIndex, 3).Value2
            Cells(outputRowIndex, 9).Value2 = Cells(inputRowIndex, 4).Value2

            ' Process next input row.
            inputRowIndex = inputRowIndex + 1

        ElseIf Cells(outputRowIndex, 6).Value2 = Cells(inputRowIndex, 1).Value2 And Cells(outputRowIndex, 7).Value2 = Cells(inputRowIndex, 2).Value2 Then

            ' Cumulate values in column H from column C.
            Cells(outputRowIndex, 8).Value2 = Cells(outputRowIndex, 8).Value2 + Cells(inputRowIndex, 3).Value2

            ' Process next input row.
            inputRowIndex = inputRowIndex + 1

        Else

            ' We have a new input row. Increment outputRowIndex.
            outputRowIndex = outputRowIndex + 1

        End If
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: This did EXACTLY what I needed, and it was so easy to alter. It seems way too sleek after being so in my head about this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This would work provided your data is sorted alphabetically by Column A, and then by Column B:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
Dim LRow As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet name
    LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LRow To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(i,1) = .Cells(i-1, 1) And .Cells(i,2) = .Cells(i-1, 2) Then
            .Cells(i-1,3) = .Cells(i-1,3) + .Cells(i,3)
            .Cells(i-1,4) = Application.Max(.Cells(i-1,4), .Cells(i,4))
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```